# Unable to install composer. Any suggestion will appreciate

Tags: windows-10, composer-php

> The command interpreter is missing:
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

[image]

Comment: I suspect your `PATH` is broken. Open a new cmd window and type in `set | sort` and copy-and-paste the output to your question (cmd uses right-click to copy after making a selection). (Do NOT post a screenshot of the window).

Comment: Thanks @Dai But C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe is already exists in my system. Don't understand what to do.

Comment: I didn't ask you if `cmd.exe` exists or not. I said that I think your `PATH` environment-variable is broken. Again, **please post the output of `set | sort` to your question** so we can see if your environment is broken or not.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/JNpQVL.jpg